# LM1496 maximum input voltage

Tags: integrated-circuit, modulation

one last question like that. I have the LM1496. The datasheet says that the maximum input voltage is 5V.

[DATASHEET](http://web.mit.edu/6.301/www/LM1496.pdf)

The question is why is this true? What determines these 5V limit?

Thank you!

Comment: Read the datasheet carefully, there is only one 5 V limit and that is not the input voltage. It is the **commonmode input voltage range**. And why do you need to know **why** certain limits are there ? There can be many reasons and only the designers of the chip know and need to know. As a user you only need to follow them if you want to use the IC as intended.

Comment: Well, it is clearly defined in the datasheet "Absolute Maximum Ratings". So, my teacher asks why is it so? How did the designers make it like that? Like, which part of the schematic puts such a limitation to the input signal? Sorry, if I am not asking clearly.

Comment: You're right, there is a comment in the text saying that the differential mode input voltage is also max 5 V. I am stupified why this is **not in the maximum ratings table** as all max ratings should be there. So that's why I only saw the commonmode rating. I agree with Neil_UK's answer btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the abs max for the supply is given as 30v, which is determined by collector-base and collector-emitter junctions, the abs max for the differential inputs is only 5v.

If you look at the schematic for any of the differential inputs, you see a pair of common emitter transistors, with the input applied across their bases. Any base-emitter junction when forward biassed looks like an ordinary diode, and will start conducting significantly at 0.7v (ish). However, the reverse biased emitter-base junction is not a 'good' diode, in most silicon BJT implementations that junction breaks down at around 5v, and not particularly robustly like a zener diode diode does. Significant reverse breakdown current can damage the transistor. The purpose of the diff input limit is to keep those junctions out of reverse breakdown.

Comment: This is correct and the reason why the BE diode has a lower breakdown than the BC diode is because the doping level is higher in the emitter, this makes the depletion layer thinner causing the reverse voltage to exist across a smaller distance (compared to the same situation in a shallower doped collector). The emitter needs a higher doping level if you want the BJT to have a high beta.